# If my resultset consists of grouped and summed records, how can I then sum/avg these?

Tags: mysql, sum, average

I can't help but think there's a simple way to do this - but I want to make sure I do it right and don't miss any simplicity that the community is bound to offer! I have two tables: `order` and `line`, to model orders place and items in those orders respectively, in a 1-to-many relationship like you'd expect. Each record in the `line` relation has a foreign key to the `order`.

I want to create a simple report to work out the average weight of all orders for the last 6 months. The `weight` is stored in the `line` table and represents the weight of **a single item**, which needs working out by using the quantity (`qty`). My plan was to `sum` the rows together first, then work out the average on them, but although the `sum` seems to work fine, I'm not sure how to apply the average here. Likewise, I'm not sure how to get the sum of all these sums so I can manually make the calculation.

**Example SQL**

```
SELECT 
    SUM(a.weight * a.qty)
FROM
    line AS a
        LEFT JOIN
    order AS b ON a.order_id = b.id
WHERE
    b.datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND b.status = 'P'
GROUP BY a.order_id
ORDER BY b.datetime ASC;
```

**Example Results**

```
20.0000
66.7400
20.7300
7.5000
7.1100
```

How should I take these results to work out the average, or at least the total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to get there from your existing query (using a derived table):

```
SELECT AVG(weight) AS Average, SUM(weight) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(a.weight * a.qty) AS weight
    FROM
        `line` AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        `order` AS b ON a.order_id = b.id
    WHERE
        b.datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND b.status = 'P'
    GROUP BY a.order_id
) a
```

Comment: I'll add the backticks... ;)